# xcode cloud build fails

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode-cloud

I connected the xcode cloud to my git repo. The repo that I can build the iPhone app successfully, can't build and has issues.

My build fails by 5 errors:

```
Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-chemnitz/Pods-chemnitz-resources-Release-output-files.xcfilelist'

Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-chemnitz/Pods-chemnitz-resources-Release-input-files.xcfilelist'

Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-chemnitz/Pods-chemnitz-frameworks-Release-input-files.xcfilelist'

Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-chemnitz/Pods-chemnitz-frameworks-Release-output-files.xcfilelist'

unable to open configuration settings file
```

and then I tried to add pods-chemnitz folder to my git. So these problems are gone but a new issue comes up.

```
The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

I already updated the cocoapods and pod. That didn't work. any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

No need to copy the pods project. These files are generated by the `flutter build macos` command. You have to run the command after Xcode pulls your code from Github. Follow these [instructions](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/cd#xcode-cloud) to create a post-clone script that sets up the Flutter environment for your project.
Then add this line before the `cd ios && pod install` line:

```
# Make sure to replace every ios with macos in the whole script
# e.g. flutter precache --macos
flutter build macos
```